# How to get Body raw JSON data from Postman to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, postman

I have the variable colors and a value in the raw data in JSON format. I want to get the value from postman to python. How can I get the body raw data in python? That postman body raw data image ->
[colors raw data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImeH5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the **odoo** tool developed by **python**. That odoo get raw data method little change the method. Maybe this way works in python

```
@http.route('/cams/biometrics 3.0/',method=["POST"], csrf=False, auth='public', type = "http")
def generate_attendance(self, **params):
    data = json.loads(request.httprequest.data)
    json_object = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request the data straight from the server with HTTP requests:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
r = requests.get('192.168.1.6:8069/web/raw?default=red')
r.json()
```

Or export the data from postman in to a `.json` file and read the file using `open()`

```
with open('example.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
```

Comment: **requests.get()** method return response and full content of that link. This is not  return the body raw data . So pls tell any other method read to json raw data @LTJ